# how to remove last few characters in regex?

Tags: regex

My page URL is http://sample.com/category/news/page/6/

I have to trim `page/6/` from the url using regex pattern. Note: the page number can be more than 1 digit.

this is what I got.

```
string.regex("/page/[0-9]/","")
```

Comment: In *what* language/environment?

Comment: you should specify the language you are working with...that would help you to get more relevant answers and in some cases better alternative solutions..

Comment: I suggest you use Rubular (rubular.com) to experiment. You can use a group around the last few characters, and regex-replace it with empty-string to get rid of it.

Comment: Search the web This is easy to learn. Also you should probably use .trim()

Comment: `string.regex("/page/[0-9]+/$","")` would seem the obvious choice, if your current query works for a single digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a plus sign to match 1 *or more* digits:

```
string.regex("/page/[0-9]+/", "")
```

---

I suspect you may need to assign the result too:

```
string = string.regex("/page/[0-9]+/", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

http://rubular.com/r/HvzXhTFnAJ

`page\/\d+\/$` will work, assuming it all always be at the end of the line (or in this case, a URL).